# Método postUrl de WebView no manda correctamente String por Post

Tags: java, android-studio, webview, utf-8

Os comento mi situación, estoy intentando mandar una cadena de texto por **POST** a una **Web View**.

El código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
 String postData = "variable=asdfg+asdfg";
 String url = "http://miurl.es";

 try {
        miWebView.postUrl(url,postData.getBytes( "UTF-8"));
 } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding","Encoding Exception" +e.toString());
 }
```

La cadena se envía correctamente, el problema viene que al mostrarla en la **Web View** estoy viendo que se ha sustituido el carácter `+` por un espacio en blanco, quedando la cadena así: `asdfg asdfg`

¿por qué al codificar en **UTF-8** se comporta así?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado.

He hecho un `UrlEncoder.encode` a la variable y funciona correctamente:

```
postData = "variable=" + URLEncoder.encode("asdfg+asdfg", "UTF-8");
```